# How to run two Angular projects on the same port

Tags: angular, port

I am developping a project where I have more than one angular projects. I would like to launch them on the same port (localhost:4000). Is this possible? Can Angular launch an app of two projects on the same port?

Answer (score 0):

You only have to host both project on their respective directory (IIS configuration needed) and build/deploy your apps with the base-href option:

```
ng build --prod --base-href=/admin // admin app
ng build --prod // public app
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to combine them under one project.

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects", 
  "projects": {
    "artists": {
         //This section contains the setting for the artists project      
    },
    "user": {
        //This section contains the setting for the user project
    }},
  "defaultProject": "artists"    
}
```

I believe you are looking for something like this:
https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-multiple-apps-in-one-project/

Comment: but   "defaultProject": "artists"    artists only working but i want to two project run single prot

Comment: Sorry then I misunderstood the question. This is not the solution for running to projects are the same time.